# PHP check if string has numbers together

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, expression

I need to filter a message text, basically the message text shouldn't contain a phone number. which means i need to check if there is a continues pattern or series of numbers in a string. i'm doing this in codeigniter. now i'm using following type of code to do this,

```
if (preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $msg ) >= 7) {
   $status = 'pending';
   $read = 'no';
}
```

what it does is count all the numeric characters in the message text and if count is greater than 7 its not passing trough. but i need to check if there is a continues number / a phone number. please help.

Comment: you have to refer the preg_match_all manual, and see what it returns. and do your homework.

Comment: We do not have a [mcve] here.  Your question is Unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming phone number to be of 7 continuous digits at least, you can use negative lookbehind like

```
^(?!.*\d{7})
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ0mK4/1)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/^(?!.*\\d{7}).*/m"; 
$str = "1234567\n123456\n12345673536"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/bZam0o)**

Comment: cool. but i changed the string to `$str = "123 what 12589 whatever 123852963"; ` then it returns an empty array

Comment: @Dhananjaya yeah..it will return empty because length of `123852963` is greater than 7..So the message is containing a phone number which you don't want to allow

Comment: **@rock321987** well assume it just a message from one user to a another. system should not allow them to share phone numbers. normally phone numbers are 8 digits long. so i need to check if the massage text contain any 8 digit phone number, but there is an another issue with how they define their phone number. some write it like 1234 5678 and some are like 123 45678 and others like 12345678. is there any way i could filter all those.

Comment: @Dhananjaya is space only the delimiter?

Comment: yes but we can't hope that users always follow the spaces no? what if the use `-` sign or something else ?

Comment: @Dhananjaya can there be multiple delimiters like `123 34-678` or is `123a345g678` valid?

Comment: no there cannot be letters between numbers, thats not possible. but there can be `-` signs and spaces.

Comment: @Dhananjaya right now what I am able to think is a two step process..you can use `\d+(?:[-\s]\d+)*` to find number separated by `-` or space as delimiter..for the above found string you can count the number of digits using `preg_match_all('\d')`

Comment: @Dhananjaya wait..you can use `^(?!.*(?:[-\s]*\d){8})` in single step regex

Comment: pretty much there but it also captures if the length of the number less than 8. here what i've done. `/^(?!.*\d{9}).*/m` problem is it captures `abc 1234 abcd` this as well. can we make this work if it greater than or equal 7 digits but less than or equal to 9 digits?

Comment: @Dhananjaya capturing `abc 1234 abcd` is correct because there is no consecutive 8 digits

Comment: @Dhananjaya also `^(?!.*\d(?:[-\s]*\d){7})` is better

Comment: cool, its working perfectly. thanks a lot. i should practice regular expressions myself :P thanks again. cheers!